# Corelated currents DNL in thermometer DAC

Tags: dac

I understand that DNL is measured as the standart deviation of subtraction of two voltages where each one is normal distributed.

for example:
if our step is from 6I to 7I then then its I4+I2 to I4+I2+I1 to 111 in binary weighted where as in thermometer it 6I1 to 7I1.
DNL of binary: stadrt diviation of subtraction of random number is sqrt of their power 2 sum)
sqrt(4+2 +0+4+2+1)= sqrt(13)

in thermometer our current distributions are corelated so we subrtaract and getting DNL of 1.
But the formula shown bellow is much more comlicated.how come we just subtract?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your equation, σ is the coefficient of correlation. If your distributions are correlated, then σ = 1. If you substitute σ = 1 into the equation, you will find that it reduces to σx -σy which is what you expected.

Comment: correleation factor is "ro" its 1 so its
sqrt(sigma_x^2+sigma_y^2-sigma_x*sigma_y)
why its not sigma_x-sigma_y ?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is. The term under the square root reduces to (σx - σy)^2. Taking the square root yields σx - σy.